# Windows Live invalid redirect_url (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, onenote, windows-live

I am trying to connect to Windows Live using oauth and I am getting an error "The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid. The expected value is 'https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf' or a URL which matches the redirect URI registered for this client application."

Because Windows requires a domain for their api I have changed my localhost domain to 'blumelocal.com'

- I am using the 'omniauth-windowslive' gem and here is my omniauth.rb file

  ```
  Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do 
     provider "windowslive", 'MYCONSUMERID','MYCONSUMERSECRET', :scope => 'office.onenote'
  end
  ```
- I navigate to 'blumelocal.com:3000/auth/windowslive' (I should add, that it redirects to 'www.blumelocal.com:3000/auth/windowslive', im not sure if this is part of the issue).

routes.rb

```
get '/auth/windowslive/callback' => "users#windows_auth"
```

in the Microsoft Developer Center I have set my targetdomain to "blumelocal.com", and redirect url to "http://blumelocal.com" (and have experimented with a variety of different possibilities".

When I navigate to blumelocal.com:3000/auth/windowslive I get taken to an error page with the error at the top

Answer (score 0):

I believe in the developer center it needs to be blumelocal.com:3000, not just blumelocal.com.